# Target class [App\Http\Admin] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I was following a tutorial for a laravel 8 project and I get this error when I try to navigate to the /admin view and don't know what is causing it. The problem seems to be in the routes but I can't manage to solve it. My Controllers directory has a folder named Admin and inside I have the AdminController.php

Here is my web.php:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->middleware(['auth'])->name('dashboard');

Route::middleware(['auth', 'admin'])->name('admin.')->prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', [AdminController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
});

require __DIR__.'/auth.php';
```

My AdminController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.index');
    }
}
```

I add my Admin class in the Middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class Admin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!auth()->check() || !auth()->user()->is_admin) {
            abort(403);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please send full exception text with trace

Comment: By the way `->name('admin.')` should be `->as('admin.)`

Comment: Might be a middleware problem. Did you register your middlewares correctly?

Comment: I think so, I updated the post with my admin class in the middleware. Also I changed ->name('admin.') for ->as('admin.), but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Ok I solved it, I didn't add ` use App\Http\Middleware\Admin;  ` in kernel